# Div not appending more than one time in jquery?

Tags: jquery, append

I m trying add dynamic fields with array name, i have done it like

```
<div class="extra_subject"></div>
<button class="add_sub btn">Add</button>
<button class="rem_sub btn">Remove</button>
```

In JS i did

```
var subject_div = $('<div class="sub_add_extra">'
    +'<div class="control-group">'
        +'<label for="sub_form" class="control-label">Subject</label>'
        +'<div class="controls">'
            +'<select name="add_subject[]">'
                +'<option value="">Please Select</option>'
                 <?php foreach($sub as $row){ ?>
                    +'<option value="<?php echo $row->id; ?>" ><?php echo $row->subject_name; ?></option>'
                <?php } ?>
            +'</select>'
        +'</div>'
     +'</div>'
+'</div>');
$('.add_sub').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.extra_subject').append(subject_div);
});
$('.rem_sub').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.sub_add_extra').last().remove();
});
```

Its appending content for first time and then when i try to append its overwriting the existing div with class `.sub_add_extra` and removes properly when i click remove butto.

Comment: Append `subject_div` as a string, not a jQuery object, [see here](http://jsfiddle.net/4hWp2/3/). I don't actually know why appending the object doesn't work, hopefully someone can offer an explanation

Comment: What would happen if you changed $('.extra_subject').append(subject_div) to $(subject_div).appendTo('.extra_subject') ?

Comment: @nocturns2 It would be the same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `clone()`

```
$('.add_sub').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.extra_subject').append(subject_div.clone());
});
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/N7DEs/)
Right now you are appending the same object again and again. `clone()` will create a clone of that object and append this cloned object everytime. If you had some event attached to the original object then use `clone(true)`

Comment: ya know i would clone but lot of things need to be assigned and manipulated in that div so only i created a jquery object. but this should append as normal appending function but its overwriting any specific reason.

Comment: @sathya I have explained why it was not working in my edited answer. What problems would you face in manipulating?

Answer (score 1):

Try my creating a function like this and use on click it will work definitely

```
function addmoreoption() {
    var html_option = '<tr valign="center"><td valign="center" bgcolor="#E8E8E8" >Name</td></tr>';
    $('#more_option').append(html_option);
}
```

Comment: ya now i am using as string only :). i think its taking it as a selector but it also appending